# Scrape data in csv format without downloading csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to scrape data (using python) ,from google sheet, in csv format,without downloading the csv file. My aim is to update a database in mysql after getting information from google sheets.

Downloading the csv file would make me download the csv file again and again ,whenever the google sheet gets updated.

I have tried to use csv_reader(open('')) and putting the url of the google sheet in csv format(the link that we get after publishing to the web in csv format).

But it shows it as an invalid argument.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is a little confusing; you need to look at the csv file to see what's in it, which usually means a download when you're on the internet. Are you saying you want updates to the csv file to be mirrored to your database? Or are you looking for a way to "stream" the csv so you don't have to grab the entire file at once?

Comment: I want to update my mysql database whenever the google sheet is updated.Downloading the sheet in csv format would cause problems as i would have to download it again whenever the sheet is updated.If I could somehow scrape the csv file through the link ...then that would solve the problem, I guess

Comment: I'm afraid you'll always have to download it to be able to read the file. If you wanted to have only the updates, you'd have to make something custom that executes queries when users modify the excel file.